# Why does pandas dataframe with datetime index return that an index is in the dataframe if it's in the range of dates within the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Why does pandas dataframe with datetime index return that an index is in the dataframe if it's in the range of dates within the dataframe? I am writing code to return True and execute some steps if a date e.g. '2020-03-07' exits in the dataframe. For dates before and after the daterange of rows in the dataframe it's clear that the index doesn't exist and `'date' in df.index` returns false.

How can I ensure that `'date' in df.index` only returns *True* when the index exists?

[image: Image shows the index results]

### Reproducible

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(365)
data = {'a': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(150)],
        'date': pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='1h', periods=150).tolist()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# remove dates between 2020-05-20 and 2020-05-25
df = df[(df.index < '2020-05-20') | (df.index >= '2020-05-25')].copy(deep=True)

print(df.index)

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-19 00:00:00', '2020-05-19 01:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 02:00:00', '2020-05-19 03:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 04:00:00', '2020-05-19 05:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 06:00:00', '2020-05-19 07:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 08:00:00', '2020-05-19 09:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 10:00:00', '2020-05-19 11:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 12:00:00', '2020-05-19 13:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 14:00:00', '2020-05-19 15:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 16:00:00', '2020-05-19 17:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 18:00:00', '2020-05-19 19:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 20:00:00', '2020-05-19 21:00:00',
               '2020-05-19 22:00:00', '2020-05-19 23:00:00',
               '2020-05-25 00:00:00', '2020-05-25 01:00:00',
               '2020-05-25 02:00:00', '2020-05-25 03:00:00',
               '2020-05-25 04:00:00', '2020-05-25 05:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)

print('2020-05-20' in df.index)
>>> True

df[df.index == '2020-05-20']

# produces empty dataframe
date    a
```

Comment: That's unexpected behavior. Can you share your data and code? I can't replicate it with a basic `pd.DateTimeIndex` object.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour neither.

Comment: You can use `df.loc['2020-3-15':'2020-3-15'].any()`.

Comment: Perhaps your `df` was pointing to a subset shallow copy of a bigger frame, where the `index` does contain the date?

Comment: Strangely enough, this issue doesn't occur with `'2020-05-20' in df[df.index >= '2020-05-25'].index`, but does occur with the joint range.  `'2020-05-20' in df.index.values` also returns `False` instead of `True`, so I'd suspect there's some handling in `pd.Index` object that differentiates the behaviour.

Comment: `df.loc['2020-05-20'].empty` will work as a valid check.  You'll have to adjust your logic.  `True` if empty.

Comment: The culprit resides in the union range `'2020-05-23' in (df.index[df.index < '2020-05-20'] | df.index[df.index > '2020-05-25'])` returns `True`.  I'd suggest digging there first.

Comment: @HenryYik what does it mean to point to a subset shallow copy of a bigger frame if the specific index is not part of the indices and the dataframe in question is the only dataframe in use?

Comment: @shadowtalker and Benoit, the script added by Trenton is exactly like my dataset. thanks Trenton..

Comment: @r.ook , Henry and Trenton, the different methods you use to check work better than the pandas  ```'date' in df.index``` , i can live with those. many tx

Comment: @r.ook is that expected/documented behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to find out much.  It seems to exhibit this behaviour with outside range only (i.e. `'19'` won't exist in `(>20 & < 23) | >25`.  I'm rather limited on time now so may dig further later, so decided to just share my findings so far.